# How to say "go to school up to the fourth grade"?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

I'm not sure how to translate this sentence:

> My grandmother couldn't do much work since she only went to school up to
>   the fourth grade.

I found online that "fourth grade" in the US is equivalent to CM1 (cours moyen 1ère année) in France.
I would try like this:

> Ma grand-mère ne pouvait pas faire beaucoup de choses étant donné
>   qu’elle n’est allée à l’école que jusqu’au CM1.

Would it be better to avoid CM1 and just say that she went to school for four years?

> Ma grand-mère ne pouvait pas faire beaucoup de choses étant donné qu'elle n'est allée à l’école que pendant quatre ans.

Comment: l'option CM1 me parait plus pertinente, même si elle suppose que le lecteur soit familier avec le nom de classes  française.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ma grand-mère ne pouvait pas faire grand chose étant donné qu’elle n’avait même pas terminé l’école primaire.

Should you want to more precisely state until what grade she went to school while staying school system neutral, you can also say:

> Elle n'était allée à l'école que jusqu'à neuf ans.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a Canadian thing, but we're happy to number years in French as we do in English. Could we avoid the loss of precision here by saying something like "Elle avait dû quitter l'école avant la quatrième année"?

Comment: @LukeSawczak I believe France is the only country counting grades a reversed way. *La quatrième année* without more precision would be meaningless here. That might be *la quatrième année de primaire* but this isn't very idiomatic unlike *quatrième année de médecine* for example. A better expression can be *l'avant-dernière année de primaire* but I don't think the added precision is that important in this sentence.

Comment: Peut-être pas essentiel, mais j'apprécie l'ajout de l'exemple avec son âge, qui répond bien à mon souci. Merci !

Comment: @jlliagre in Belgium primary school goes from year 1 to 6, from 6 to 12 year old, so the 4th wouldn't be "avant-dernière". But the exemple with the age is perfect and fits any scholar system.

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful to make precise the difference in the two educational systems; that dépends on what you intend to do with the translated text;

- Ma grand-mère n'avait pas beaucoup de moyens comme elle n'avait pas pu aller plus loin que la quatrième année d'étude élémentaire, ce qui correspond à peu près au cours moyen 1 de l'école primaire en France.

If a precise information is not essential to the context, you might do away with such detail;

- Ma grand-mère n'avait pas beaucoup de moyens comme elle n'avait pas pu arriver jusqu'au collège ou au lycée.